# Use more than one letter in short-value

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I'm using `clap` to parse arguments. I want to use the single dash (-) and more than one character in the argument, like `-Fmin 1`. Adding `long("Fmin")` gives me that but with two dashes (--).

I'm aware that using a single dash and single character together is the norm. But is it possible to have clap use more than a single character when using the short() form? Or override the long-form so it defaults to a single dash?

```
let matches = App::new("clap")
    .arg(Arg::with_name("Fmin")
        .required(false)
        .takes_value(true)
        .short("Fmin")
        .multiple(false)
        .possible_values(&["min"])
    )
    .get_matches();
```

Comment: Ugh… But why though? Principle of least astonishment: most modern tools use `-` for short options and `-Fmin` is the same as `-F -m -i -n`, and `--` for long options. Don't do this to your users.

Comment: You are correct. Clap can reduce options with possible_values(), so this can reduce ambiguity.

Comment: @mcarton might be a requirement to replace an existing tool, single-dash long options are common in some contexts e.g. Sun/Oracle or Apple-provided CLI tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to have clap use more than a single character when using the short() form? Or override the long-form so it defaults to a single dash?

Judging by [this issue](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/1210), single-hyphen long options are not yet supported by clap.